# Graphical Depiction of all the Salesforce Certifications?

Tags: certification

Is there a graphical depiction of all the Salesforce certifications that shows all the prerequisite exams, the stages of getting all the certifications, which certifications count towards Fullforce Certification for Partners, which exams are now deprecated, transition exams for the deprecated Developer exams, and how the upcoming Domain Specialist and Domain Architect exams will fit into all of this?

Answer (score 10):

Check out this great new visual summary on Salesforce Ben:
[https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-certification-pathways/]
[image: Visual depiction of all Salesforce certs]

**Disclaimer:** this older diagram was last updated in 2017 and may not reflect certs added since then.

[image: Unofficial Infographic of all the Salesforce Certifications]
What a coincidence, I just prepared one!

[View in Google Drawings](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1BXxt5Svs-sNweb9lH4JOUAiMqP18vWC5a1AygkfysQc/edit).

Comment: this diagram is outstanding, do you have a twitter account?

Comment: I'm on Twitter @abd3721, but rarely post

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:** this diagram was last updated in 2017 and may not reflect certs added since then.

Here is a simpler view of this information, showing only the currently available certifications.
[image: Simpler graphical view of all certifications]

[View in Google Drawings](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1qnsdQ5sMj8fZR1gESe0ajf0mv6rSkzU38wzzksumhUk/edit)